# Why do I have to set the content in ContentControl?

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, contentcontrol

I have a relatively simple question that I do not understand. Suppose I have a ContentControl and a ContentTemplate specified and I would like to do the following:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" DataContext="{Binding User}" />
```

However to my surprise, this completely fails, while the following line works perfectly:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding User}" />
```

Upon closer examination, the first line gives a surprising `null` as its DataContext, whereas the latter one has the correct DataContext.

Could someone explain to me what is going on?

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you bind to property `User` that is defined is some `ViewModel`. Than you don't have to set `DataContext`:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding User}" />
```

And is more common write this:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding User}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think in the first example Content Property is null so you should do this

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding User}" />
```

Comment: It seems to me if I do this `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding User}" />` is kind of redundant or not? Because with the second line, the DataContext will be magically set correctly.

Comment: then main problem that you have is setting null to Content.. whereas when you put `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserView}" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding User}" />` you can use the "user object with other property